# Not able to add UIBarButton to navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have downloaded this source code [here](https://github.com/Busta117/SBInstagram) and its working fine.

But I need to add a button on `SBInstagramCollectionViewController`
 navigationbar ,I tried following code and am not able to see that button there (Looks like somethng wrong).

```
//Add button to NavigationController
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = 
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@“back”, @"")
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                 target:self 
                                 action:@selector(goBack)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Please help me....

Comment: Check you have a value for `@“back”` in localizable. Or try with `initWithTitle:@"back"`.

Comment: tried both not working

Comment: I tried your code in the same sample and its working. can you please check that your navigation bar is not hidden

Comment: can u share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your code for `UIBarButtonItem` in the `viewDidLoad` method of `SBInstagramCollectionViewController.m` class in the project

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

         [super viewDidLoad];

         //Other code

         //Add button to NavigationController
         UIBarButtonItem *backButton =
         [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  
                                         target:self action:@selector(goBack)];

         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
}
```

Comment: currently the code is viewdidload itself please check the attached screns

Comment: currently the code is in viewdidload itself please check the attached screenshts

Comment: I have tried using the UIBarButtonItem in the code sample , and its working fine. I simply downloaded the code from the link you provided and added the code to for in UIBarButtonItem in the SBInstagramCollectionViewController.m class. have a look http://s11.postimg.org/u43e5wz43/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_01_Sep_2014_12_37_09_P.png